# Recalibrating Landmarks in Google Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

Is there is a way to use a physical landmark so that if the tango “looks” at the landmark, the tango can recalibrate its origin point in the virtual world?  I’m finding that if the tango loses its tracking, when it recovers, its position in the virtual world is shifted.

Comment: Does the tango understand which way is **true** north? Or is its rotation “foward” direction always relative to how you are holding the tango when you start up?

Comment: The Tango stack doesn't know which way is north, but you can use the compass API from Android to find out which is north, and correlated Tango data with the north data.

Comment: Also, with the original answer, do you think a reset position function would solve it? or you are thinking about something else?